# Get the VNet of a Subnet with AZ cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, vnet

I know that one way to get the VNet, is by using awk on the the id of a subnet. But what if I want to get the vnet of a subnet by using the subnet id, with az cli?

I guess I can use the `az network vnet list` command but I cannot figure out the proper filter that will let me search by subnets.[].id.

Comment: You can use this CLI command: `az network vnet list --query "[?contains(subnets[].id, '$subnet_id')].name" --output tsv` to get expected [result](https://i.imgur.com/R2Py6Zh.png)

Comment: thank you very much @Sridevi! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **VNet name** from Subnet ID via Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:

```bash
subnet_id="/subscriptions/subID/resourceGroups/rgName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VnetName/subnets/subnetName"
az network vnet list --query "[?contains(subnets[].id, '$subnet_id')].name" --output tsv
```

**Response:**

[image]